# Open iOS application from Facebook Messenger bot

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I currently have a bot that works on Facebook Messenger channel.  I can open urls within the in-app browser without a problem.

I also have an iOS application, that supports deep linking.  I have tried to use quick replies and buttons, but neither will open the iOS application.

is this possible within the messenger platform?

Comment: The closest thing to this in Bot Framework is `ActivityTpe.OpenURL`. If you are able to send the user to a URL that will open the IOS app somehow, that could be an option for you.

Comment: Yea, that is currently what i have setup, however the messenger in app browser opens it, instead of setting them to an external browser/app.  wasn't sure if we could override that.